# Extract Values from heavily nested list of dictionaries with duplicate key value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

Trying to extract Total Cash and Cash Equivalent values from complex and messy list of dictionaries. A shortened version of the structure follows below.

I've tried: maps, Dataframe.from_dict & .from_records. Trying to avoid using RE.

I'm stumped.

```html
 [{u'Fields': [],
  u'ReportDate': u'2 June 2016',
  u'ReportID': u'BalanceSheet',
  u'ReportName': u'Balance Sheet',
  u'ReportTitles': [u'Balance Sheet',
                    u'Test Company',
                    u'As at 30 June 2016'],
  u'ReportType': u'BalanceSheet',
  u'Rows': [{u'Cells': [{u'Value': u''},
                        {u'Value': u'30 Jun 2016'},
                        {u'Value': u'30 Jun 2015'}],
             u'RowType': u'Header'},
            {u'RowType': u'Section', u'Rows': [], u'Title': u'Assets'},
            {u'RowType': u'Section',
             u'Rows': [{u'Cells': [{u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'c0bxx922-cc31-4d53-b060-cbf23511`2533'}],
                                    u'Value': u'Test Bank 1'},
                                   {u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'c1b4xx22-cc31-4d53-b060-cb45282533'}],
                                    u'Value': u'5555.20'},
                                   {u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'c2b44922-cc31-4d53-b060-cbf4532582533'}],
                                    u'Value': u'5555.20'}],
                        u'RowType': u'Row'},
                       {u'Cells': [{u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'290c7c3c-a712-4ads6f-9a2f-3d5258aad5a9e'}],
                                    u'Value': u'Test Bank 2'},
                                   {u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'490c7c32-axxxdf6f-9a2f-3db682a3ad5a9e'}],
                                    u'Value': u'55555.20'},
                                   {u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'490xxc3c-a71-adsf6f-9a2f-3d3aad5a9e'}],
                                    u'Value': u'55555.20'}],
                        u'RowType': u'Row'},
                       {u'Cells': [{u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'c6d4da40-f0df1b0-8f7d-xx45b1405'}],
                                    u'Value': u'Test Bank 3'},
                                   {u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'c6d4da4fg-df-41b0-8f7d-54xx345b1405'}],
                                    u'Value': u'5555.20'},
                                   {u'Attributes': [{u'Id': u'account',
                                                     u'Value': u'c6d4dafgss-9-41b0-8f7d-60xx5b1405'}],
                                    u'Value': u'5555.20'}],
                        u'RowType': u'Row'},
                    {u'Cells': [{u'Value': u'Total Cash and Cash Equivalents'},
                                {u'Value': u'5555555.20'},
                                {u'Value': u'5555555.20'}],
                     u'RowType': u'SummaryRow'}],
          u'Title': u'Cash and Cash Equivalents'},
         {u'RowType': u'Section',
```

Comment: Why not use `json`?

Comment: I'm stuck with this output regrettably.

Comment: what is duplicate about the key value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the data will have exactly the format from above and you really just need these two values, you can access it directly (assuming `data` is your above structure):

```
print data[0]['Rows'][2]['Rows'][3]['Cells'][1]['Value']
print data[0]['Rows'][2]['Rows'][3]['Cells'][2]['Value']
```

However, this is error prone, both in writing down the correct expression and with respect to changes of the order of the lists (which might not be defined in your format). Since there is a semantical structure behind the data, you could translate the raw data back into an easily accessible object. You might want to change some details but this is a good starting point:

```
from collections import Mapping
import pandas as pd

class Report(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.sections = OrderedDict()
        for row in data.pop('Rows'):
            getattr(self, 'make_%s' % row['RowType'])(row)
        self.__dict__.update(data)

    def make_Header(self, row):
        self.header = [c['Value'] for c in row['Cells']]

    def make_Section(self, sec):
        def make_row(row):
            cells = [c['Value'] for c in row['Cells']]
            return pd.Series(map(float, cells[1:]), name=cells[0])

        self.sections[sec['Title']] = pd.DataFrame(make_row(r) for r in sec['Rows'])

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.sections[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sections)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.sections)


report = Report(data[0])
print report.ReportName
print report['Cash and Cash Equivalents']
```

Comment: In python3 you will need to call the appropriate namespace, eg. collections.Mapping.

Comment: You mean collections.abc.Mapping. Btw. would you accept the above answer as a solution?

Comment: Sorry. My first SE post. Will do